Slack CLI | Failure on 'slack run'
I am currently following a basic tutorial to design a custom Slack bot that can post issues to GitHub. I followed the steps as displayed on https://api.slack.com/tutorials/tracks/create-github-issues-in-workflows, however upon running 'slack build' I am running into the error sdk_hook_not_found.
Running slack doctor presents no issues with the system (Operating System, Git); Slack (CLI, Configurations, Credentials), however under Project, Configurations is fine, but Runtime and Dependencies are flagged as errors.
All that is being returned is the vague error sdk_hook_not_found. What is even more frustrating is that on the official documentation this error is highlighyed, and it effectively points to a template, which is the exact one I'm using!
My slack.json file:
{
  "hooks": {
    "get-hooks": "deno run -q --allow-read --allow-net https://deno.land/x/deno_slack_hooks/mod.ts"
  }
}

I re-initialised the project several times in suspicion that I misconfigured the build. I also went as far as installing WSL to attempt running slack run on a Ubuntu terminal, however I am still facing the same issue.

I also received this error until I installed Deno, the CLI tool used in the hook. You can find Deno here: https://deno.com/
